# SQL query to return the most recently updated rows - added/deleted

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table in my database which acts like an interface between two applications. One inserts and deletes rows in this table while the other has to poll to get the most recently added/deleted rows. The app that writes to the database is third-party and I am writing the code for querying the database in python (using pymssql). The table has an id as a key and the id is incremented by 1 when a row is added.

I think that `SELECT FROM table WHERE id > index` will return the rows that are added to the table considering that "index" in my code stores the most recent id that is read. But how will I know what rows have been deleted? Is there a way to have a single query that will give the rows that are updated - both added and deleted?

Comment: Since the rows that have been deleted are no longer in the table, it might be difficult to write a query to retrieve them. You will need to do that on the client side.

Comment: If you can try using a "delete flag" and an "update time stamp". That will make this a lot easier. All other solutions are going to be difficult. (comparing all of records in one table to the other)

Comment: It seems from the original question that the table layout is specified by the third-party application.

Answer (score 2):

You could add Triggers to your table that inserts the IDs (or more of the data) for the rows that were both inserted and deleted. This could then be used in your own application accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. I will check how to add Triggers for this.

Comment: Can I have the trigger procedure call a function in my python script?